# How I can retrieve login details using radio button in asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi Friends,

I am working Asp.Net MVC 5 project.

I want RadionButton like this on HomePage

Looks like:

O Admin
O Team Member
O Team Leader
O Customer

**USER will select anyone of above radio buttons**

Username __________________

Password __________________

**and after that he will enter his credentials to login**

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you are using Identity, but I do not know this from your post. Once a user logs in you can get their roles using

```
User.IsInRole("RoleName");
```

And you can get all roles wtih

```
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
var userRoles = userManager.GetRoles(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

If you are NOT using identity I think System.web.security namespace has Roles and lets you simple.

```
Roles.GetAllRoles()
```

I think that just gets all roles on the system, read into System.web.security, I know it is very easy to work with but it has been a while.

A user is placed in a Role, they should not place themselves in a role, and the user does not need to know what role they are in, the application can tell them based on login credentials, more specifically the application behaves based on credentials.